# Converting android application to work with Galaxy Note

Tags: java, android, galaxy, samsung-mobile

c
can anyone tell me why when I install my application on Galaxy Note it mixes my layout!!!
I'm working on 3.7 WVGA (Galaxy one)

thanks so much =)

Comment: You really haven't given enough information to evaluate your question. Things like the layout file and which directory its in will help.

Comment: What does "mixes my layout" mean? Screenshots would also help.

Comment: @dmon I meant messed my layout so the txtView and EditText moved from their orginal location